# How to Convert 2 Columns of Data to Bullet List?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, csv

I have a csv of data that exists as a hierarchy.

```
ColumnA = Parent
ColumnB = Child
```

There may be multiple children per parent.

I would like to convert the excel data to a bullet list hierarchy. (if there's a different name for the bullet list that I'm after please let me know - that could be why my searches have been no good).

Example:

[image: Excel Columns to Bullet List]

I have thousands of rows and do not want to manually copy paste into the bullet list.

I'm hoping there's some kind of transpose option I just cant figure out.
Also if Excel/Word don't have it but something else does, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Using any of the answers below, then you could use a formula to get your bullets and further indent the Children using a formula such as: `=IF(LEFT(F3,1)="P",CONCAT(CHAR(149),F3),CONCAT("   ",CHAR(149),F3))

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table may do what you want:

Original table:

[image]

Pivot table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build the "result" in helper columns, e.g. C and D:

If the A-column on a row has the same content as on the row above, don't display it, but on any error - DO display A1.

That last thing enables seeing $A$1 in $C$1, but may cause odd results further down, so maybe use `IF(CELL("address",A1)="A1",A1,"ERROR!")` instead of just `A1`
... after the last `,` before the last `)`.
Formulas without this last check shown below.

C1:
`=IFERROR(IF(A1<>OFFSET(A1,-1,0),A1,""),A1)`
D1:
`=B1`
Select C1, D1; Copy down

Want it in a single column?
E1:
`=C1 & CHAR(9) & D1`
Copy down.
Copy and Paste column E into Word, select all rows, set it to be a bulleted list.